# C++ variable declaration re: memory usage

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi I know this is a very silly/basic question, but what is the difference between the code like:-

```
int *i;
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
  {
    i = static_cast<int *>(getNthCon(j));
    i->xyz
  }
```

and, some thing like this :-

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
  {
    int *i = static_cast<int *>(getNthCon(j));
    i->xyz;
  }
```

I mean, are these code extremely same in logic, or would there be any difference due to its local nature ?

Comment: Neither is valid C.  `static_cast` is a C++ thing.  Also, there is no memory allocation here.

Comment: And why is it not valid in C/C++ ?

Comment: FatalError : I noticed that, how can I improve that ?

Comment: Because C\C++ is not a language; it is a terrible term typically used to describe C++.  This is a C++ question, so I am retagging it.

Comment: @potatoman: There is no language called "C/C++". C and C++ are two different (but closely related) languages, and `static_cast` exists only in C++.

Comment: As for the quesiton itself, why not take a peek at the disassembly?  That will answer your question very quickly.

Comment: Ed S : Could you do that and mark it as the answer to the question

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : Why is there no memory allocation ?

Comment: @potatoman: In the context of C++, memory allocation relates to using `new` (`malloc` in C).

Comment: @potatoman - Your examples, by the way, are terribly confusing. It would have been better if you could have pasted literal C++ code in instead of whatever this was. In particular, it isn't clear if you are asking about `int*`s or about classes, since `i->xyz` is nonsensical for `int*`.

Comment: @Robᵩ : fp_ContainerObject* pContainer = static_cast<fp_ContainerObject*>(getNthCon(i)); is the exact code

Comment: @potatoman: Then put that in your *question*, not in a comment. Stack Overflow isn't a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One practical difference is the scope of `i`. In the first case, `i` continues to exist after the final iteration of the loop. In the second it does not.

There may be some case where you want to know the value of `i` after all of the computation is complete. In that case, use the second pattern.

A less practical difference is the nature of the `=` token in each case. In the first example `i = ...` indicates *assignment*. In the second example, `int *i = ...` indicates *initialization*. Some types (but not `int*` nor `fp_ContainerObject*`) might treat assignment and initialization differently.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little difference between them.

In the first code sample, `i` is declared outside the loop, so you're re-using the same pointer variable on each iteration. In the second, `i` is local to the body of the loop.

Since `i` is not used outside the loop, and the value assigned to it in one iteration is not used in future iterations, it's better style to declare it locally, as in the second sample.

Incidentally, `i` is a bad name for a pointer variable; it's usually used for `int` variables, particularly ones used in `for` loops.

Comment: Tell something that is not more obvious, I think everyone gets that, apart from suggesting the appropriate variable name

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : I wanted to know the corner cases in which the 2 identical codes, give different answers.

Comment: @potatoman: How could two identical pieces of code running on the same platform give different results?  That makes no sense.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : I am still not convinced, that it would give same answer in all cases, but Ok I will take that as an answer

Comment: @EdS. : Could you look at rob's answer above

Comment: @potatoman: Not sure how that is relevant.  I said the same (re: scope), but you asked specifically about memory allocation.  Also, your two code samples are not in any way, shape, or form "identical". EDIT: Ah, you mean overloads of the `=` operators?  Well then you should have used a complex object instead of an `int*`  I suppose.  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: *"Tell something that is not more obvious"* -- You're assuming that there is something that isn't more obvious. If you don't think they'll give the same answer in all cases, then show us a case where they don't.

Answer (score 0):

For any sane optimizing compiler there will be no difference in terms of memory allocation.  The only difference will be the scope of `i`.  Here is a sample program (and yes, I realize there is a leak here):

```
#include <iostream>

int *get_some_data(int value) {
    return new int(value);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int *p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        p = get_some_data(i);
        std::cout << *p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the generated assembly output:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
01091000  push        esi  
01091001  push        edi  
    int *p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
01091002  mov         edi,dword ptr [__imp_operator new (10920A8h)]  
01091008  xor         esi,esi  
0109100A  lea         ebx,[ebx]  
        p = get_some_data(i);
01091010  push        4  
01091012  call        edi  
01091014  add         esp,4  
01091017  test        eax,eax  
01091019  je          main+1Fh (109101Fh)  
0109101B  mov         dword ptr [eax],esi  
0109101D  jmp         main+21h (1091021h)  
0109101F  xor         eax,eax  
        std::cout << *p;
01091021  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax]  
01091023  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (1092048h)]  
01091029  push        eax  
0109102A  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (1092044h)]  
01091030  inc         esi  
01091031  cmp         esi,0Ah  
01091034  jl          main+10h (1091010h)  
    }
```

Now with the pointer declared inside of the loop:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
008D1000  push        esi  
008D1001  push        edi  
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
008D1002  mov         edi,dword ptr [__imp_operator new (8D20A8h)]  
008D1008  xor         esi,esi  
008D100A  lea         ebx,[ebx]  
        int *p = get_some_data(i);
008D1010  push        4  
008D1012  call        edi  
008D1014  add         esp,4  
008D1017  test        eax,eax  
008D1019  je          main+1Fh (8D101Fh)  
008D101B  mov         dword ptr [eax],esi  
008D101D  jmp         main+21h (8D1021h)  
008D101F  xor         eax,eax  
        std::cout << *p;
008D1021  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax]  
008D1023  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (8D2048h)]  
008D1029  push        eax  
008D102A  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (8D2044h)]  
008D1030  inc         esi  
008D1031  cmp         esi,0Ah  
008D1034  jl          main+10h (8D1010h)  
    }
```

As you can see, the output is identical.  Note that, even in a *debug* build, the assembly remains identical.

Comment: @potatoman: Except for the return at the end, yes (you can even see the end curly bracket there).

Answer (score 0):

Ed S. shows that most compilers will generate the same code for both cases. But, as Mahesh points out, they're not actually identical (even beyond the obvious fact that it would be legal to use `i` outside the loop scope in version 1 but not version 2). Let me try to explain how these can both be true, in a way that isn't misleading.

First, where does the storage for `i` come from?

The standard is silent on this—as long as storage is available for the entire lifetime of the scope of `i`, it can be anywhere the compiler likes. But the typical way to deal with local variables (technically, variables with automatic storage duration) is to expand the stack frame of the appropriate scope by `sizeof(i)` bytes, and store `i` as an offset into that stack frame.

A "teaching compiler" might always create a stack frame for each scope. But a real compiler usually won't bother, especially if nothing happens on entering and exiting the loop scope. (There's no way you can tell the difference, except by looking at the assembly or breaking in with a debugger, so of course it's allowed to do this.) So, both versions will probably end up with `i` referring to the exact same offset from the function's stack frame. (Actually, it's quite plausible `i` will end up in a register, but that doesn't change anything important here.)

Now let's look at the lifecycle.

In the first case, the compiler has to default-initialize `i` where it's declared at the function scope, copy-assign into it each time through the loop, and destroy it at the end of the function scope. In the second case, the compiler has to copy-initialize `i` at the start of each loop, and destroy it at the end of each loop. Like this:

If `i` were of class type, this would be a very significant difference. (See below if it's not obvious why.) But it's not, it's a pointer. This means default initialization and destruction are both no-ops, and copy-initialization and copy-assignment are identical.

So, the lifecycle-management code will be identical in both cases: it's a copy once each time through the loop, and that's it.

In other words, the storage is allowed to be, and probably will be, the same; the lifecycle management is required to be the same.

I promised to come back to why these would be different if i were of class type.

Compare this pseudocode:

```
i.IType();
for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
  i.operator=(static_cast<IType>(getNthCon(j));
}
i.~IType();
```

to this:

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
  i.IType(static_cast<IType>(getNthCon(j));
  i.~IType();
}
```

At first glance, the first version looks "better", because it's 1 IType(), 10 operator=(IType&), and 1 ~IType(), while the second is 10 IType(IType&) and 10 ~IType(). And for some classes, this might be true. But if you think about how operator= works, it usually has to do at least the equivalent of a copy construction and a destruction.

So the real difference here is that the first version requires a default constructor and a copy-assignment operator, while the second doesn't. And if you take out that static_cast bit (so we're talking about a conversion constructor and assignment instead of copy), what you're looking at is equivalent to this:

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
  std::ifstream i(filenames[j]);
}
```

Clearly, you would try to pull i out of the loop in that case.

But again, this is only true for "most" classes; you can easily design a class for which version 2 is ridiculously bad and version 1 makes more sense.

Answer (score -2):

For every iteration, in second case, a new pointer variable is created on the stack. While in the first case, the pointer variable is created only once(i.e., before entering the loop )

Comment: This is misleading.  In all likelihood, the two code snippets will compile to identical machine code, and therefore identical stack usage.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: +1, was just about to make the same comment when yours popped up.

Comment: Also, to be pedantic; there is nothing in the standard which requires automatic storage duration to be implemented via a stack structure.  It would be better to say "the variable is created with automatic storage duration".

Comment: I don't think this should be downvoted; he may have raised it in a misleading way, but he has raised a good point. It just needs to be clarified and expanded on.